# Getting an average of the entire table when using group by

Tags: sqlite, group-by, average

I have a table of workers, their salaries and departments and need to find those departments whose lowest paid worker has a higher salary then the average for the entire workforce.

My table looks a bit like this:

WORKERS

Worker-id|salary|department-id

Now my attempt at a solution has been to use:

select department-id from workers where min(salary)

all other solutions only get me the average for each department. I could look up the average salary, then look up the minimum salaries and compare them manually but there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compute the entire average in a subquery:

```
SELECT departmentID
FROM Workers
GROUP BY departmentID
HAVING MIN(salary) > (SELECT AVG(salary)
                      FROM Workers)
```